# Jest testing a react render prop that receives a component as an argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, testing-library

Let's say I have the following wrapper component:

```
function SomeRenderComponent({ render }) {
  return <>{render({ renderArgument: <SomeComponent /> })}</>;
}
```

I would want to write an assertion like this:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("provided a renderProp expect the renderProp to be called with component", () => {
  // arrange
  const renderProp = jest.fn();

  const expected = {
    renderArgument: <SomeComponent />,
  };

  // act
  render(<SomeRenderComponent render={renderProp} />);

  // assert
  expect(renderProp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected);
});
```

While it "looks" correct, the test will fail, I'm guessing due to the fact that SomeComponent is a component.

So I guess I'm searching for something like:

```
const expected = {
  renderArgument: expect.componentIs(<SomeComponent />),
};
```

Similiar to what `expect.objectContaining` does.

I would appreciate someone showing me how to test the renderProp with `toHaveBeenCalledWith` when working with components.

Comment: Is  a <SomeComponent  /> external component ?, if it true , IMO you can done by mocking this component first, and set any value that you want,

Ref: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/28/jest-mock-default-named-export/

Comment: @funnyDev Yes it is, but I really can't get your example to work. I'm having issues with with jest hoisting the jest.mock, but I need to be able to create a jest.fn to pass it to the jest.mock with that aproach, so I can later use the jest.fn as an `expected`